# Can't align my equations properly in my proof

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment

I was wondering if anyone might be able to help me out with a spacing issue that I'm running into whenever I type out a lengthy equation. I'm trying to make my proof of the binomial theorem look clean, but I'm running into trouble when trying to align the equations in a aesthetically appealing fashion. I tried using the split equation environment, and while it made everything visible on the page, I still really don't like the spacing, I would like everything to be vertically centered (horizontally as well, though that hasn't been to big of an issue). I'm new to LaTeX, as well as this site, so I would greatly appreciate any advice (code or otherwise).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}


\noindent \textbf{Binomial Theorem:} If $n \in {\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}}$, then

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k}$$

\begin{doublespace} \end{doublespace}
\noindent \textbf{Proof:} Let $n=0$, then $(x+y)^0 = 
\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{0} \binom{0}{k}x^{k}y^{-k} = 1$.

Suppose this holds for $n \geq 1$, we need to show that it holds for $n+1$, so
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(x+y)^{n+1} = (x+y) \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k} 
\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k+1}y^{n-k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k+1}
\end{split}
\end{equation*} 
Now we reindex the first sum, replacing each occurrence of $k$ 
by $k-1$. Since the original sum extends over all values of $k$, 
so does the reindexed sum. Hence
\begin{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(x+y)^{n+1} = 
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}x^{k}y^{n-k+1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k+1} 
\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \bigg(\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}\bigg)x^{k}y^{n-k+1} 
\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}x^{k}y^{n-k+1}
\end{split}
\end{equation*} 
\end{center}
By the addition identity, this establishes the required result. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing 2 `&`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you looking for this:

[image]

Anchors  for split of equations should be present in each line of equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Binomial Theorem:} If $n \in {\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}}$, then
    \[
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k}
    \]
\noindent \textbf{Proof:} Let $n=0$, then $(x+y)^0 =
\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{0} \binom{0}{k}x^{k}y^{-k} = 1$.

Suppose this holds for $n \geq 1$, we need to show that it holds for $n+1$, so
    \[
\begin{split}
(x+y)^{n+1} 
    & = (x+y) \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k}   \\ 
    & = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k+1}y^{n-k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}
                        \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k+1}
\end{split}
    \]
Now we reindex the first sum, replacing each occurrence of $k$
by $k-1$. Since the original sum extends over all values of $k$,
so does the reindexed sum. Hence
    \[
\begin{split}
(x+y)^{n+1} 
    & = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}x^{k}y^{n-k+1} 
                    + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k+1} \\ 
    &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \bigg(\binom{n}{k-1} 
                    + \binom{n}{k}\bigg)x^{k}y^{n-k+1}          \\ 
    &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}x^{k}y^{n-k+1}
\end{split}
    \]
By the addition identity, this establishes the required result.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I will delete my answer since both are the same solution.

Comment: well, you pass me for 10 seconds (now I see) ... thank you very much for your kindness

Comment: This indeed was what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your input misses a couple of `&`, but it also has some other glitches.

1. Use environments for the logical structures such as theorems and proofs; if you use `\noindent` in the document body more than once, there's something wrong
2. Never use `$$` (see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503))
3. The syntax `{\Bbb Z}` has been replaced by `\mathbb{Z}` a couple of decades ago: use `\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}` or, even better something like below.
4. `\begin{doublespace}\end{doublespace}` does nothing at all.
5. The `\displaystyle` in the proof's first line just does harm: it spoils the line spacing, but also gives too much prominence to a trivial case

For point 1, you can use `amsthm` and a small trick for defining “named theorems”. If you want a colon instead of a period, it's just a matter of defining a theorem style (there are several examples on the site). Similarly for the typesetting of the “Proof” tag.

Why defining `\numberset` as `\mathbb` and `\Z` in terms of `\numberset`? Because this gives you much more flexibility; if your supervisor tells you that the integers and all other number set names should be typeset in fancy calligraphic, you just need to change *one* line of your document and not chasing through it for `\mathbb`.

I present here two realizations of your code; in the second one the alignment of the equals signs goes on for both displays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}

\newcommand{\NAMEDtheoremname}{}
\newtheorem*{NAMED}{\NAMEDtheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedtheorem}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\NAMEDtheoremname}{#1}\begin{NAMED}}
 {\end{NAMED}}

\begin{document}

\begin{namedtheorem}{Binomial Theorem}
If $n \in \Z_{\geq 0}$, then
\[
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k}
\]
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{proof}
Let $n=0$, then $(x+y)^0 = \sum_{k=0}^{0} \binom{0}{k}x^{k}y^{-k} = 1$.

Suppose this holds for $n \geq 1$, we need to show that it holds for $n+1$, so
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(x+y)^{n+1}
  &= (x+y) \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k} \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k+1}y^{n-k} + 
     \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k+1}
\end{split}
\end{equation*} 
Now we reindex the first sum, replacing each occurrence of $k$ 
by $k-1$. Since the original sum extends over all values of $k$, 
so does the reindexed sum. Hence
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(x+y)^{n+1}
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}x^{k}y^{n-k+1} + 
     \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k+1} \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \biggl(\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}\biggr)x^{k}y^{n-k+1} \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}x^{k}y^{n-k+1}
\end{split}
\end{equation*} 
By the addition identity, this establishes the required result. 
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}

\newcommand{\NAMEDtheoremname}{}
\newtheorem*{NAMED}{\NAMEDtheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedtheorem}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\NAMEDtheoremname}{#1}\begin{NAMED}}
 {\end{NAMED}}

\begin{document}

\begin{namedtheorem}{Binomial Theorem}
If $n \in \Z_{\geq 0}$, then
\[
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k}
\]
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{proof}
Let $n=0$, then $(x+y)^0 = \sum_{k=0}^{0} \binom{0}{k}x^{k}y^{-k} = 1$.

Suppose this holds for $n \geq 1$, we need to show that it holds for $n+1$, so
\begin{align*}
(x+y)^{n+1}
  &= (x+y) \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k} \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k+1}y^{n-k} + 
     \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k+1}
\intertext{Now we reindex the first sum, replacing each occurrence of $k$ 
by $k-1$. Since the original sum extends over all values of $k$, 
so does the reindexed sum. Hence}
(x+y)^{n+1}
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}x^{k}y^{n-k+1} + 
     \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^{k}y^{n-k+1} \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \biggl(\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}\biggr)x^{k}y^{n-k+1} \\
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}x^{k}y^{n-k+1}
\end{align*} 
By the addition identity, this establishes the required result. 
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks amazing! And thank you for those pointers! I've typed up a few documents using the double space command, and it felt redundant, but I just got into the bad habit of using it. And those new commands are going to save me an extraordinary amount of time! Thank-you so much for the help!